# Restrict single page to user agent?

Tags: .htaccess

How to restrict/block users with Firefox and Chrome user-agent who tring to accessing to this page:

```
http://example.com/test/mypage.php
http://example.com/test/mypage2.php
```

Or block entire pages in folder "test" from accessing only for Firefox and Chrome user-agent .

All another users-agents can be access to this pages regulary.

I want to do with .htaccess.

**Is this possible and how to do that? Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the server variable `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Firefox|Chrome).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test - [F]
```

---

**N.B.** Note that `User Agent strings` are notoriously unreliable indicators of the actual user agent. If, for example, an Opera browser is broadcasting a `User Agent string` containing the word `Chrome`, then that Opera browser will also be blocked by the `RewriteCond` above.